# Get the first ever recorded date of occurrence from data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this database that contains observations about snow depth. The structure is like this:

```
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID           | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| DATE_OBS     | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| SNOW_DEPTH   | int(4)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And a sample of data:

```
    +------+------------+--------------+
    | ID   | DATE_OBS   |  SNOW_DEPTH  |
    +------+------------+--------------+
    |    1 | 2002-01-01 |           58 |
    |    2 | 2002-01-01 |           58 |
    |    3 | 2002-01-02 |           61 |
    |    4 | 2002-01-03 |           60 |
    |    5 | 2002-01-04 |           64 |
    ************************************
    | 4563 | 2014-06-28 |            0 |
    | 4564 | 2014-06-29 |            0 |
    | 4565 | 2014-06-30 |            0 |
    +------+------------+--------------+
    4565 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want to know if it is possible to get some informations about the first ever recorded day with snow from my data and also the last ever recorded day with snow cover. 
I have tried with DISTINCT statement but with no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, 'FIRST_SNOW' TYPE, MIN(DATE_OBS) ,  SNOW_DEPTH FROM MY_TABLE
UNION
SELECT ID, 'LAST_SNOW' TYPE, MAX(DATE_OBS) ,  SNOW_DEPTH FROM MY_TABLE
```

OR

```
    SELECT ID, DATE_OBS, SNOW_DEPTH, 'FIRST_SNOW' TYPE FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY DATE_OBS ASC LIMIT 1
UNION
    SELECT ID, DATE_OBS, SNOW_DEPTH, 'LAST_SNOW' TYPE FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY DATE_OBS DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @julics: Happy to help with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all the records for the first and last date (or to manipulate them to get the average, or similar for each of the first day and last day):-

```
SELECT a.ID, a.DATE_OBS, a.SNOW_DEPTH 
(
    SELECT MIN(DATE_OBS) AS min_date
    FROM some_table
) sub0
INNER JOIN some_table a
ON a.DATE_OBS = sub0.min_date
UNION
SELECT a.ID, a.DATE_OBS, a.SNOW_DEPTH 
(
    SELECT MAX(DATE_OBS) AS max_date
    FROM some_table
) sub0
INNER JOIN some_table a
ON a.DATE_OBS = sub0.max_date
```

If you just want the first or last records then use the suggestion by *juergen d*